# angle for particular co-ordinate in projectile path?

Tags: physics

I have xy co-ordinate like (200,200). I know the angle calculation from the origin the ball throws. How can I find the initial velocity  to reach that particular xy co-ordinate when ball is thrown in 2d Environment?

Iam using

```
 x = v0cosq0t;
 y = v0sinq0t - (1/2)gt2.
```

but time is needed. Without time can I do it? any help please?

Comment: You might want to consider describing what each variable is. I don't know what "gt2" represents. You also have a syntax error on line 2. "." instead of ";"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want the ball to hit that specific point (200,200) at the apex of its path. Well, my physics is a bit rusty, but this is what I've thrown together:

`v_y = square_root(2*g*y)`,

where g is a positive number reflecting the acceleration due to gravity, and y being how high you want to go  (200 in this case).

`v_x = (x*g) / v_y`,

where x is how far in the x direction you want to go (200 in this case), g is as before, and Vy is the answer we got in the previous equation.

These equations remove the need for an angle. However, if you'd rather have the velocity + angle, that's simple:

`v0 = square_root(v_x^2 + v_y^2)`

and

`angle = arctan(v_y / v_x)`.

Here is the derivation, if you're interested:

`(1/2)at^2 + v_yt + 0 = y`

`(1/2)at^2 + v_yt - y = 0`

by quadratic formula,

`t = (-v_y +/- square_root(v_y^2 - 2ay)) / a`

we also have another equation, because at the apex the vertical velocity is 0:

`0 = v_y + at`

substitute:

`0 = v_y + (-v_y +/- square_root(v_y^2 - 2ay))`

`0 = square_root(v_y^2 - 2ay)`

`0 = v_y^2 - 2ay`

`v_y = square_root(-2ay)`, or

`v_y = square_root(2gy)`

For v_x:

`v_x*t = x`

from before, t = v_y / a, so

`v_x = (x*g)/v_y`

I hope that made enough sense.

Answer (score 0):

Im sure you can assume the velocity change is instantaneous. Games physics always has some 'dodgy' parts in it because it is too computationally expensive or not important enough to get right down the low granularity information.

You can start the velocity ass instantaneous, and then using a timer class to measure then time between each frame (very rough way of doing it), or you can have a timer class set up in an update loop that will update the physics every x seconds.