# Projectile hit coordinates at the apex of its path

Tags: physics, chipmunk

I have a projectile that I would like to pass through specific coordinates at the apex of its path.  I have been using a superb equation that giogadi outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182242/angle-for-particular-co-ordinate-in-projectile-path/2182406#2182406), by plugging in the velocity values it produces into chipmunk's cpBodyApplyImpulse function.

The equation has one drawback that I haven't been able to figure out.  It only works when the coordinates that I want to hit have a y value higher than the cannon (where my projectile starts).  This means that I can't shoot at a downward angle.

Can anybody help me find a suitable equation that works no matter where the target is in relation to the cannon?

Comment: If you point the cannon downwards, and don't worry about hitting the ground, then you'll not have an apex on the path (i.e. point where the vertical component of the velocity is zero). The vertical component of the velocity will simply increase without bound. Do you just want the projectile to pass through the point? I think this will give you an unlimited number of possible paths to choose from.

Comment: If the target is below the cannon, it is impossible to hit the target at the apex (highest point) of the path. If the angle is less than horizontal, the apex is the starting point of the projectile!

Comment: You guys are right on, I should have phrased my question better.  When shooting below the cannon, I simply would like it to pass through the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out above, there isn't any way to make the apex be lower than the height of the cannon (without making gravity work backwards). However, it is possible to make the projectile pass through a point below the cannon; the equations are all [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile). The equation you need to solve is:

```
angle = arctan((v^2 [+-]sqrt(v^4 - g*(x^2+2*y*v^2)))/g*x)
```

where you choose a velocity and plug in the x and y positions of the target - assuming the cannon is at (0,0). The `[+-]` thing means that you can choose either root. If the argument to the square root function is negative (an imaginary root) you need a larger velocity. So, if you are "in range" you have two possible angles for any particular velocity (other than in the maximum range 45 degree case where the two roots should give the same answer).

I suspect one trajectory will tend to 'look' much more sensible than the other, but that's something to play around with once you have something working. You may want to stick with the apex grazing code for the cases where the target is above the cannon.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thank you Andrew!